# NetBeans can't find main class

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I am trying to create a program using applets in NetBeans and I am having a problem. Whenever I try to run a program it says "Project does not have main class set". I was able to get around this by adding 
`public static void main (String[] args)` but my program doesn't do anything. I tried just a generic program to see if it was my coding and it still didn't work. Do I need to reset my NetBeans or is it a coding error?
Here is the code I got from the Oracle website that doesn't work

```
    import javax.swing.JApplet;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class HelloWorld extends JApplet {
    //Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
    public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
                add(lbl);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
    }
    }
```

This is the code for my program:

```
package robot;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.lang.Object;


public class Robot extends JApplet {
private Rectangle rect; 

public void init(){
rect = new Rectangle (0, 0, 20,20);


this.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
 } 

public void paint(Graphics g) {
super.paint(g);
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
{
this.setSize(355, 355);
}
Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;

g1.setColor(Color.black);
g1.fill(rect);
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{ 
if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
rect.setLocation ( rect.x,rect.y=+20 );
repaint();
 }
if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
rect.setLocation ( rect.x,rect.y=-20 );
repaint();

 }
if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
rect.setLocation ( rect.x =+20, rect.y );
repaint();
 }
if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
rect.setLocation ( rect.x =-20,rect.y);
repaint();
 }

}


}
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code snippets in 2 separate files and when i run HelloWorld.java the application is running.

Comment: I was able to run the program if I right clicked in my code then hit "Run Project" but whenever I try and use the run project button it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you run the whole project? You have java files. Just right click on HelloWorld.java and run it. In eclipse I just pressed run when I had HelloWorld.java opened.

Comment: Ive just always done it that way, but now that I am getting into more complex programs I will start just running the file

Comment: Try and tell me if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to run the program if I right clicked in my code then hit "Run Project" but whenever I try and use the run project button it doesn't work.

The second way used to run it simply isn't valid for an applet.  That is for an **application.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set main class by left click on `project -> run` and select main class:
 [image]

Comment: i edited your answer just to remove my downvote , i clicked on it by mistake